# Error unmarshalling message body from amqp

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp, unmarshalling

I'm trying to send a JSON inside the body of the message using AMQP and receive it. The message sends without any error, however I can't unmarshall it on the other side. I get a `unexpected end of JSON input` error.

**JSON:**

```
var jsonStr = []byte(`
{
    "name": "Test",
    "phone_number": "12345"
}`)
err = files.SendMessageToCore(jsonStr, "event.saveorder")
if err != nil {
    logr.Error("Error sending a message to rabbitmq:", fmt.Sprintf("%v", err))
}
```

**SendMessageToCore function:**

```
func SendMessageToCore(body []byte, routingKey string) error {
pb, err := GetRabbitPublisher()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

var message amqp.Message
message.Exchange = "example"
message.RoutingKey = routingKey
message.Body = body
messageByte, err := json.Marshal(message)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = (*pb).Publish(amqp.Message{Exchange: message.Exchange, RoutingKey: message.RoutingKey, Body: messageByte})
if err != nil {
    return err
}
fmt.Println("Message was successfully sent")
return nil
```

}

**Unmarshalling part:**

```
func SaveOrderEventHandler(mes amqp.Message) *amqp.Message {
var incomingMessage amqp.Message
if err := json.Unmarshal(mes.Body, &incomingMessage); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return nil
}

var user foodDomain.User
if err := json.Unmarshal(incomingMessage.Body, &user); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error unmarshalling incomingMessage body: ", err) //Error appears here
    return nil
}
fmt.Println(user.PhoneNumber)

return nil
```

}

**User struct:**

```
type User struct {
   Name        string `json:"name"`
   PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number"`
}
```

Comment: Your message is already in `json` byte, why `marshal` one more time before publishing ? And also why `unmarshal` twice ? You should be able to directly `unmarshal` into `&user` (i.e. `json.Unmarshal(mes.Body, &user)` )

Answer (score 0):

In your `SendMessageToCore` you already initialized `amqb.Message`. No need to re-initialize in the `Publish` func, just pass your initialized `message`. Also, your `json` string `body` is already in `jsonByte`, so no need to `marshal` it once more. 
For instance -

```golang
func SendMessageToCore(body []byte, routingKey string) error {
    pb, err := GetRabbitPublisher()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var message amqp.Message
    message.Exchange = "example"
    message.RoutingKey = routingKey
    message.Body = body
    err = (*pb).Publish(message)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Message was successfully sent")
    return nil
}
```

And your `mes` already in `amqp.Message` type, so no need to unmarshal `mes.Body` into `amqp.Message` type variable.
Just directly `unmarshal` your `mes.Body` into `user`.

```golang
func SaveOrderEventHandler(mes amqp.Message) *amqp.Message {
    var user foodDomain.User
    if err := json.Unmarshal(mes.Body, &user); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }

    fmt.Println(user.PhoneNumber)

    return nil
}
```